# Directing to facebook login page

Tags: java, json, facebook-graph-api

I want to direct to facebook login page through my program since I want to extract some facebook data ie I want to extract data in this link "https://www.facebook.com/search/109301862430120/likers" likewise I want to extract all other page's user details who like it. I tried many ways even extracted json data of that page.But it does not provide the details of what I needed.But it gives the details like this not the user details who liked it

```
{

"genre":"Blues",
"hometown":"Springfield, MA",
"website":"http://www.tajblues.com",
"link":"http://www.facebook.com/tajmahal",
"about":"Come visit Taj's channel on YOUTUBE!http://www.youtube.
com/user/TajMahalMusic and you'll be emailed each time new video is posted!",
"current_location":"BERKELEY, California ",
"id":"133245295466",
"cover":{
    "source":"http://sphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-frc1
/t1/s720x720/1959464_10153758939890467_1167909590_n.jpg",
    "cover_id":"10153758939890467",
    "offset_y":19,
    "offset_x":0
},
"category":"Musician/band",
"username":"tajmahal",
"bio":"Henry Saint Clair Fredericks, who goes by the stage name Taj Mahal,
 is an  internationally recognized blues musician who folds various forms
 of world music into his offerings. A self-taught singer-songwriter who plays 
the guitar, banjo and harmonica (among many other instruments), Mahal has done 
much to reshape the definition and scope of blues music during his 40+ year 
career by fusing it with nontraditional forms, including sounds from the 
Caribbean, Africa and the South Pacific.",
"likes":93945,
"name":"Taj Mahal",
"were_here_count":0,
"is_published":true,
"talking_about_count":4848
}
```

Comment: Have you look at the Facebook api?  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: @TANguyen I tried all of them

Comment: @TANguyen I tried all possible methods and tried using my program refer this link which I posted earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090850/extracting-links-of-a-facebook-page/22091711?noredirect=1#comment33510658_22091711